# Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'toUpperCase' of undefined react state item

Tags: javascript, reactjs, webpack

I'm new to React and Javascript and I'm trying to render the following React component:

```
'use strict';
var React = require('react');
import ToReadList from './toreadlist.js';

var ToRead = React.createClass({
getInitialState: function() {
    return { bookTitles: [] };
},
handleSubmit: function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    this.state.bookTitles.push(React.findDOMNode(this.refs.bookTitleInput).value.trim());
    this.setState({items: this.state.bookTitles});
},
render: function() {
    return (<div>
        <form onSubmit={this.handleSubmit}><input type="text" ref="bookTitleInput"></input>
            <input type="submit"></input></form>
            <ToReadList bookTitles={this.state.bookTitles} />
    </div>
           );
}
});

module.exports = ToRead;
```

But I am having the following error on my console: "**Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'toUpperCase' of undefined**"

I tried to debug (because the error is obscure to me and no line in my code is indicated) and noticed that this particular line:

```
this.state.bookTitles.push()
```

causes the error.

Please help!

**Edit** 
The error is caused by a webpack var injection function:

```
function autoGenerateWrapperClass(type) {
      return ReactClass.createClass({
        tagName: type.toUpperCase(),
        render: function() {
          return new ReactElement(
            type,
            null,
            null,
            null,
            null,
            this.props
          );
        }
      });
    }
```

Comment: In your code is no `.toUpperCase`.

Comment: Do you mean that it is called nowhere?

Comment: this.state.bookTitles.push(React.findDOMNode(this.refs.bookTitleInput));
If the above line is in error try to push with a constant string. I think findDOMNode is returning null and push is doing some kind of uppercase on it which is resulting in error.

Comment: @Biswanath yes i tried this: this.state.bookTitles.push("this is a title");
same thing.
I added this: console.log(React.findDOMNode(this.refs.bookTitleInput)) and the input is correctly printed.
It is worth to notice that this code (this.state.bookTitles.push("this is a title");) works perfectly under React 0.12 but the problem appears when I upgrade to 0.13

Comment: @panther the error appears in the "function autoGenerateWrapperClass(type) {
   return ReactClass.createClass({
     tagName: type.toUpperCase(),
 " code of  WEBPACK VAR INJECTION

Answer (score 6, accepted):

My appologies for the poor quality of this post.

I resolved the issue.

Finally, the problem came from the included component:

```
<ToReadList bookTitles={this.state.bookTitles} />
```

The error appeared when `this.state.bookTitles.push(React.findDOMNode(this.refs.bookTitleInput).value.trim());` was called because `bookTitles` triggers the error inside the component when it is not empty (i.e `<ToReadList bookTitles={["mastery", "foundation"]} />` triggers exactly the same error)

The compenent in question's code is as such:

```
'use strict';
var React = require('react');
import {ToReadListItem} from './todoreadlistitem.js';

var ToReadList = React.createClass({
    render: function() {
        return (<ul>
            {this.props.bookTitles.map(function(bookTitle){ 
                return (<li>
                    <ToReadListItem bookTitle={bookTitle} isChecked={false}/>
                </li>);
            })}
        </ul>);
    }

});

module.exports = ToReadList;
```

Changing this line:

```
import {ToReadListItem} from './todoreadlistitem.js';
```

To this:

```
import ToReadListItem from './todoreadlistitem.js';
```

I know, it is not a great idea to mix es6 syntax with flat one, but I permit myself doing it since the app is for experimentation purposes.

I hope I helped to make things clearer.

Comment: Why not just do `var ToReadListItem = require('./todoreadlistitem.js');`?

Comment: For the sake of trying new things ;)

Answer (score 6):

`findDOMNode()` uses the `toUpperCase()` function which actually is called on a null.

**Example**

```
var x = null
x.toUpperCase()// results in this error.
```

If you could post the `findDOMNode()` code, we could trace out the error.

**OR**

Make sure that the `toUpperCase()` is called on a `non-null object`.

Comment: I added this code: console.log(React.findDOMNode(this.refs.bookTitleInput).value.trim());
which prints the input content.
The error happens in webpack var injection "function autoGenerateWrapperClass(type) { return ReactClass.createClass({ tagName: type.toUpperCase(), ..." function

Answer (score 3):

I guess the problem is because you try to modify the state directly. Try this:

```
var newBookTitles = this.state.bookTitles;
var value = React.findDOMNode(this.refs.bookTitleInput).value.trim();
newBookTitles.push(value);
 this.setState({bookTitles: newBookTitles});
```

I hope it will solve your problem.

Comment: I was going to say this before OP answered his question.  Directly modifying the state produces undefined behavior.  +1

Comment: The issue is resolved.
But I take your remark in consideration
Especially that the same approach is adopted here http://facebook.github.io/react/docs/tutorial.html#optimization-optimistic-updates

Answer (score 2):

Importing component with incorrect name gave me the same error.

I had imported it as 
`var AreaChart = Charts.AreaChart;`

where as in `Charts.js` it was exported with a small 'c' :

`Areachart: Areachart`

Changing it to `AreaChart: Areachart` in `Charts.js` while exporting solved it.