# React 0.13.3 giving Super expression must either be null or a function, not object

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6

I have this code

```
import React from 'react';
import Component from 'react';
import Bar from './Bar.es6.js';
import Chart from './Chart.es6.js';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';

export default class App extends Component {
    render() {
        return (
            <div class="app">
                <Chart width={this.props.width}
                    height={this.props.height}>
                <Bar data={this.state.data}
                    width={this.props.width}
                    height={this.props.height}>
                </Bar>
                </Chart>
            </div>
        );
    }
};

function select(state) {
    return state;
}

export default connect(select)(App);
```

This gives me an error

```
Uncaught TypeError: Super expression must either be null or a function, not object
```

From this question

[reactjs giving error Uncaught TypeError: Super expression must either be null or a function, not undefined](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30116430/reactjs-giving-error-uncaught-typeerror-super-expression-must-either-be-null-or)

It should have gone away with React v0.13.x, and I have 0.13.3

What's going on?

Comment: should you be exporting both the class and the connect() ?

Comment: You can only have a one default export.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
import Component from 'react';
```

imports the `react` namespace into `Component`. That's an object. It's the same as `import React from 'react';` and equivalent to

```
var Component = require('react');
```

and that's *not* what is done in the linked question.

You want

```
class App extends React.Component { }
```

Comment: So I initially did that to avoid a Cannot read property 'toUpperCase' of undefined at autoGenerateWrapperClass error, because of this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30643604/uncaught-typeerror-cannot-read-property-touppercase-of-undefined-react-state?rq=1, which is now back

Comment: Even with the second solution?

Comment: Yeah...although do I generally have to take out all import { x, y } from z statements?

Comment: It depends. `import a from 'foo';` imports `'foo'`s **default** export. `import {a, b} from 'foo';` imports its **named** exports.

Comment: Ok, well when I do what you do, I get that error back. I'm not sure why as the error message is very unhelpful. When I try and not use { } and use the sub components namespaced, I get React.applyMiddleware is undefined

Comment: Updated the answer because I missed that you already import `React`. `React` definitely doesn't have a property "applyMiddleware". Not sure what the error means as well, but you definitely have to use `React.Component`.

Comment: Is that supposed to be `class App extends React.Component { }`?

Comment: @FelixKling no problem! At first I wondered if it was some syntax I just don't understand yet, but figured out from the context it must just be a typo.